# Smallest no of balls in the box?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, pell-type-equations

A box contains white and black balls. When two balls are drawn without replacement suppose the probability that both are white is  1 /3.

a) Find smallest number of balls in the box ? 
b) How small can the total number of balls be if black balls are even in  number  ?

I considered no of white balls as 'n' and no of black balls as 'm'.

So for first two balls to be white it would be 
{n/(m+n)}*{(n-1)/(m+n-1)} = 1/3 . But how to solve further ? we have only one equation

Can anyone please explain in detail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There being 1 equation simply means that it has an infinite number of real solutions. But we don't want any real solution. The solutions need to be positive integers, and the problem asks for the smallest one, so you need to experiment.

Simplify the notation a bit by making $M$ the total number of balls. Your equation is $\frac{n}{M}\frac{n-1}{M-1} = \frac{1}{3}$, or $3n(n-1) = M(M - 1)$. Since everything is in integers in this last equation, you must have 3 divides either $M$ or $M-1$. What is the smallest value of $M$ such that 3 divides $M$ or $M-1$? And does that value of $M$ allow you to find an integer $n$ satisfying $3n(n-1) = M(M - 1)$?

Comment: thank you so much for your time and reply. Using the equation given by you, the minimum integer value that n can take is 2. which gives us m as 6 or 7. bu the answer is given to be 3. the smallest no of balls is 3. Is that i am going wrong somewhere ?

Comment: Where did you get $m = 6$ or 7? that does not follow at all from my equation. Further, if you know $n$, there is only one $m$ (or using my version, one $M$) that corresponds to it, not two different values. The smallest value of $M$ such that 3 divides $M$ or $M-1$ is obviously 3, not 6 or 7. And note that $M \ne m$ - maybe I should have called it $T$ or something else instead.

Comment: Ohh i see where i went wrong. Thanks Paul.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{n}{m+n}\frac{n-1}{m+n-1} = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$\frac{n(n-1)}{(m+n)(m+n-1)} = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$\frac{n(n-1)}{m^2 + 2nm + n^2 - m - n} = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$\frac{n(n-1)}{(m+n)^2 - (m+n)} = \frac{1}{3}$$
Let us now set $m+n = B$, the number of total balls
$$3(n^2-n) = B^2 - B$$
$$B^2 - B - 3(n^2-n) = 0$$
$$B = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1+12(n^2-n)}}{2}$$
$$m = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1+12(n^2-n)}}{2}-n$$
Since $m$ must be an integer, $1+12(n^2-n)$ must be some $k^2$ for some whole number $k$. We throw in some values for $n$ until we get an integer. The first one we get is $n=2$, yielding $k=5$.
$$m = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{25}}{2}-2$$
$m$ must be positive, throwing out one solution of the quadratic
$$\therefore n=2, \,\,m = 1$$

Comment: This solution shows that $m=1$ and $n=2$, matching the solution given by Paul. I prefer this solution a bit as it requires a little less guess-work... the only part requiring any is to throw in some values of $n$ to find some $k^2$.

Comment: A little less guesswork? You have to try two values to get an integer. In my version, the very first one to try gives the answer, with significantly simpler mathematics, too.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Looking back through your solution I suppose you are right, and your solution can be generalized much more... I didn't read through it as carefully as I should have. I see your point now. Mine makes a bit more sense to me, but I can see how your solution is simpler.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you so much. I liked both solutions.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen How to write in numerator denominator form ? Can you please share the syntax ? The way you have written its more clear. I have written equation in one line which I guess doesn't seem clear

Comment: @thealgorithm Sure thing! I've only been helping out on Stack Exchange for 3 days now, and I've already got most of MathJax down... it's pretty easy! First of all, consult [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) often... it is your best friend! The most important thing to know is that MathJax is delimited by either \$insertMath\$ or \$\$insertMath\$\$, for inline and new-line text respectively. All special functions are delimited with a backslash before the function.

Comment: Using these, your equation is written as \$\frac{n}{m+n}\frac{n-1}{m+n-1} = \frac{1}{3}\$ in MathJax (you can make it new-line text as I did in my post by using the method I outlined in the first comment)

Answer (score -2):

there is another solution to this problem:

Let a and b denote the number of white and black balls in the box. We can thus define  the probability of the event as.

$$P(W_2|W_1)P(W_1) = ((a-1)/(a+b-1))\cdot (a/(a+b))$$
As $a/(a+b) > (a-1)/(a+b-1)$
Since $\min(x,y)\le GM(x,y)\le\max(x,y)$
we can say that  $((a-1)/(a+b-1))^2 < 1/3 < (a/(a+b))^2$

Solving these inequalities we can say that

$$b / (\sqrt3-1) < a <  (b-1+\sqrt3) / (\sqrt3-1)$$
if we compute $b = 1$ we find an interval of $1.366 < a < 2.366$ so we can say that $a = 2$ and the minimum number of balls is $3$.

You can compute as many $b$ as you wish...

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Equations are much easier to read when formatted with Mathjax. I helped you with it this time and tried to follow your logic. If you don't like my edits you can revert.